# iPhone dock connector seems to have bent pins, is this a hazard

Tags: iphone, lightning

The dock connector on my iPhone 4S appears to have some bent pins (I think those crushed copper lines in the photo are pins). The phone charges, but it thinks that it is always connected to the dock. That is an annoyance, but the phone seems to work fine otherwise. However, I am worried that the bent pins may be a hazard of some type. Is there any risk of shock or fire?

[image: iPhone dock connector with bent pins]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pull those pieces out with a plier (or tweezers) so to remove any potential shorts.

Comment: I grabbed a jewelry screwdriver and scrubbed the pins against the wall, they all broke and fell out. On the positive side, my iPhone now no longer thinks it's always connected to a dock. Unfortunately my FM receiver no longer works. Thankfully it still charges. I hope there are no other problems. My biggest concern was fire/shock, or some other potential hazard. It seems like some of the pins may have been ground pins -http://pinouts.ru/CellularPhones-A-N/iPhone_connector_pinout.shtml - will this be a problem?